# How to autocomplete text field in javascript conditionally based on datasource?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I want to be able to perform "conditional autocompleting" based on the text that is typed in the query. For example:

A user can:

Type "f", which then pull up suggest names for all field names "field_name", "field_age" as suggestions.

If the user then types or selects "field_name" then types "=" in the box, then there would be a request for a specific list of data unique to"field_name" such as [Albert, Bob, Clarisse].

If the user then types " " (space) then the options would be remotely pulled in or accessed ["AND", "OR", "==", "!=". Once the user selects or types say "==" then based on the current string so far "field_name == ' ' ", the list [Albert, Bob, Clarisse] would be used.

If the user were to instead type field_age... then a request would go out specficially for a list or json object of ages [7,3,6] that would then pop up. A sample input in a search box would be:

field_name = 'Albert' AND field_age = '7'

I've seen a library typeahead.js, but it appears to just pull in all the data to be autocompleted as opposed to "data as needed" (in this case, names and ages. the reason being is that names could be gigantic, with many many names and I do not want to client to download all the values for every single possible field available as it would be a rather large download).

What is the best way to do this? Is typeahead.js support this or some alternate library better?

Comment: That's a pretty interesting case, I am not sure which library can do this, but I am sure typeahead.js can not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't [dijit/form/ComboBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox.html) deliver what you're looking for here?

There are lots of [Similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocomplete+dojo) to your question posted on here - have a browse through them...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use two boxes, seems like the most logical approach to me. The first one narrows things down by name, and the second one narrows it down by age or some other field. This way you can then do an AND/OR SQL statement. You can also, of course, limit the number of responses that you send back from the server, as you are correct, sending back a thousand+ auto completes is of little use. As far as which library, at that point you should be able to use any autocomplete library you wish, there are probably a few dozen of them. jquery UI, dojo, or my favorite Select2.

You can also of course write you own method to utilize a single text box instead of two. In which case I would suggest doing it on the server-side instead of client-side. I don't know of any libraries that can do this automatically on the client or server-side.

Comment: Do you have any server-side recommendations for this sort of thing using a single text box?

Comment: @Setsuna a programer lol, but no seriously, I have a feeling you're going to have to get into some custom string splitting or dare I say it, RegEx. What server-side language are you using?